# Print a text file with printmanager

Tags: android

I have an aplicattion and I need to print a text file in a portatil printer, I did this using bluetooth, but i would like to use PrintManager from the android version 4.4.

I don't know how connect to the printer.

I need some help. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how connect to the printer

You don't connect to the printer. You tell Android what to print. It lets the user choose an available printer and configure the print job, then it works with the printer manufacturer's `PrintService` (or Google Cloud Print, if appropriate) to actually print the request.

This requires your printer manufacturer to have created a `PrintService` for the printer and have published that `PrintService` as an app, probably on the Play Store, or to support the printer through Google Cloud Print.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry, but I think that I didn't understand, my printer is like this: http://www.inputservice.com.br/LeopardoA7.html . In this case I need a PrintService from Leopardo A7, Is this? ther's no other way do to print? Thank's for the support.